# stringr extract text based on captialization and position

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am attempting to extract some words (country names) from strings. The strings are list elements, for example,

```
myList <- list(associations =  c("Madeup speciesone: \r\n\t\t\t\t",  "Foobarae foobar: Russia - 123,",
                              "Foobarus foobar France -  7007,Italy -  7007,Portugal -  6919,Ukraine -  42264,Russia -  7009,", 
                              "Foobarus foobarbar", 
                              "Foobaria foobariana f. sp. foobaricol Japan - 254, China - 256,"))
```

I want to extract the country name, and for example, I could do this:

```
Country_name <- lapply(myList, pattern = "China|France|Italy|Ukraine", str_extract_all)
country_list <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(Country_name[[1]])){
  country_list[i] <- paste(Country_name[[1]][[i]], collapse = ",")
}
```

But would need to list all possible countries for it to work, which seems laborious.

Is there a way using regular expressions to extract all of the country names? Something like start at the second capitalized word and then extract all countries until the end of the string?

Using something like `lapply(myList, word, 3)` doesn’t quite work because of the variable length of the species names (e.g. Foobaria foobariana f. sp. foobaricol).

```
# desired output
country_list <- c("","Russia","France,Italy,Portugal,Ukraine,Russia","","Japan,China")
```

Comment: Please, see if the `myList` object is what you intended. There wasn't the `list` part in the original post and I edited supposing it was needed.

Comment: With the `myList` as edited, you could try: `lapply(str_extract_all(myList$associations,"(?!^)[A-Z]\\w+"),paste,collapse=",")`.

Comment: @nicola the myList edit is what I intended. Your code works. `\\w+` is a word boundary, correct? and

Comment: `\\w+` refers to any word character, excluding word boundaries. You could also write it like `(?<!^)[:upper:][:lower:]+`.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract country names using the package `countrycode`

```
library(countrycode)
countries <- as.data.frame(countrycode_data$country.name)
```

If you want to stick to your code, you can create a string consisting of all country names that are separated by "|"

```
all <- paste(countrycode_data$country.name, collapse="|")
```

Then running

```
Country_name <- lapply(myList, pattern = all, str_extract_all)

country_list <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(Country_name[[1]])){
country_list[i] <- paste(Country_name[[1]][[i]], collapse = ",")
}
```

should give you the result:

```
myList <- list(associations =  c("Madeup speciesone: \r\n\t\t\t\t",  "Foobarae foobar: Russia - 123,",
                             "Foobarus foobar France -  7007,Italy -  7007,Portugal -  6919,Ukraine -  42264,Russia -  7009,", 
                             "Foobarus foobarbar", 
                             "Foobaria foobariana f. sp. foobaricol Japan - 254, China - 256,",
                             "Germany",
                             "555Senegal")) 

Country_name <- lapply(myList, pattern = all, str_extract_all)

country_list <- vector()

for(i in 1:length(Country_name[[1]])){
country_list[i] <- paste(Country_name[[1]][[i]], collapse = ",")
}

country_list
[1] ""          ""                "France,Italy,Portugal,Ukraine"
[4] ""          "Japan,China"     "Germany"                      
[7] "Senegal"
```